# How to get a sqltable in to cache of an web application?

Tags: sql, .net, caching, web-applications

I am working  on asp.net and C# web application and I just want to cache a particular table of sqldatbase in to cache of the web application on application start and need to destroy it in application end?

How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by application start and end.
If you mean start is the first time the application or aspx page is loaded, then you might want to look at CacheDependency. You can find a lot of documentation on this on the Internet.

If application start is every time a certain page is loaded, you might just want to use a Dataset or Datatable to cache the table.